# Stop Vue page from loading till data (fetch) is loaded

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, anchor, vuejs3

I am trying to figure out how I can stop my page from loading until my fetch task is done. This is because I am encountering a few issues:

- I can't re-use the same data, so I have to re-fetch it every time. (Changing views after it is loaded works, but reloading a route breaks)
- Anchor links don't work, if I have the anchor link #about below some featured items, the #about section will be moved lower because the featured items just finished loading. I can't really use a skeleton loading system, because the amount of items is dynamic.

This is the current code I am working with:

```js
  data() {
    return {
      collections: [],
      items: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchCollections() {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/collections')
      return await res.json()
    },
    async fetchItems() {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/items')
      return await res.json()
    }
  },
  async created() {
    this.collections = await this.fetchCollections()
    this.items = await this.fetchItems()
  }
```

For all, I know this could be completely bad practice and I am doing everything wrong. Please don't shame me, I am new to Vue and still a bit rough with JavaScript.

#### To summarize

The intended behavior is for the page to *finish* loading after the data has been pulled from the backend.

The current behavior means my site will load, and then after a millisecond delay, the content will pop up from the finished fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your route depends on some data to be fetched, the correct way of doing this is through Vue-router's Navigation guards. [Here's docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html) about this problem.
Here's some code for your use case:

```
async function fetchData() {
  const resCol = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/collections');
  const resColJson = await resCol.json();
  const resItems = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/items');
  const resItemsJson = await resItems.json();
  return { resColJson, resItemsJson };
}
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      collections: [],
      items: []
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    fetchData().then(({ resColJson, resItemsJson } ) => {
      next((vm) => {
        vm.collections = resColJson;
        vm.items = resItemsJson;
      });
    });
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate() {
    fetchData().then(({ resColJson, resItemsJson } ) => {
      this.collections = resColJson;
      this.items = resItemsJson;
    });
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I somehow didn't realize a navigation guard could be used in a component. Guess I gotta learn to read better.

Comment: Nevermind, this solution is returning the promise rather than the actual json content. By having a second `.then` I was able to fetch the data on the initial load, however the view doesn't render and the data isn't fetched when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Sorry, I had two next calls in a single guard. Check updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but my issue is that collections is supposed to receive an array, but res.json() is returning a promise with the necessary array nested in it

`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Promise`

Comment: I see, fixed it again. Seems I could rewrite it better if I abstract the code into a separate async function.

Comment: Thank you, its working! I'll try to clean the code up into different functions, but you got me the base functionality down. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Cleaned up the code for you :) Could you check if this is working too?